# Is it possible to use async await with regular function which is not marked async in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-functional-component

*Please note, below code is not actual code. There`s lot omitted for bravity.*

I am using react with typescript and all my components are functional components.

I have following function which is like

```
export const filterData = (data) => {
  // do lots of filtering on data, does not make any api calls.
  // only do Array.filter, map etc to remove unwanted data
};
```

This function is defined in separate utils file and imported in my react component. I am using it as following

```
    //Fetch data using hook from API
    const receivedDataFromAPI = useDetails(detailsParams);// Data is already received here. Verified that data is coming from network tab and console log 
    const cleanedData = allFilter(receivedDataFromAPI);

    const allFilter = async (receivedData: IData) => {
      const data = await filterData(receivedData);
      // other code
    }
```

Earlier I was not using it with async await but then, execution was not waiting for filterData to return result. After doing lots of trial and error, I came to async await and code is working fine now. The question is above pattern ok or I need to make filterData function async?

Comment: You can await something that's not a promise, it's just pointless to do so. Does filterData actually return a promise? If so, marking it async would allow you to use await *inside* it, but would make no difference *outside* it.

Comment: if `filterData` is sync function, there is no need "to wait" for it finish executing. Because it will wait as default.

Comment: Are you fetching the `data` from an API?

Comment: It may be worth sharing the contents of your `filterData` function

Comment: @BlackMath @Rezaa91 no, it` doing basically array filter on data received from API. It is not fetching any data

Comment: @GauravChauhan What do you mean receiving data from API is not fetching any data? This is contradictory, because receiving data from API is the same as fetching data from that API. Can you include the part where you receive the data from API?

Comment: @BlackMath I am saying data is already received and then passed to this function. Added more code in question for clarity.

Comment: Did you the networks tab on your browser? Does it show the request? I only ask this since you said the API does not return data.

Comment: @AbrarHossain, data is fetched already. As i said in code.

Comment: Given your requirements there's no need to make `filterData` `async`. And if you don't declare the function as async then no need to await for it; so you can remove that await before the invocation as well.